# razor mvc trying to use button click to invoke server method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

somewhere?   Seen this asked many times, but solutions do not work..

the button definition above is standard.  But, the question being asked here is how to invoke any method, anywhere when a click happens??  I can use the  tag for a link; i would like to use a button.
The answer will be Whatever is needed to make: 
A button such that when the button is clicked, some method on one of the controllers can be invoked?

razor MVC web page.  Add a button and it invokes a method, possibly passing data? so something in C# code in the controller.

UPDATE: question too confused, vague, not clear enough.

put this into the details.cshtml page.  button click now calls method 'test' in controller 'Index'.  web page crashes saying no, there aint no Actionresult and no View controller found for test, looked in /Index/test (and ~10 other file locations)

this could be useful, but the goal is to call some method that could do some c# code, modify webpage contents then return and continue where it was

what happens now, that shouldnt, is the button click pulls a new web page.  what should happen is the button click method is called, its an empty "return", and the page simply continues where it was.

Added a view for test.  now? blank page

Comment: Please fix your question to provide more details.

Comment: Not really clear what your question is, but best guess is you want to handle the click event of a button, call a controller method that returns some data and then update the existing page with that data. If so then you need to use ajax to call the server and return either a partial view or json, then update the DOM with the returned data.

Comment: @MaxPower, You don't have to render the whole page. If you just want to send the value of one control to the controller, or update the value of one  html element, you can easily do that using ajax. I suggest you spend some time studying jquery.

Answer (score 0):

There are several samples on how this would work and you really should provide more detail in what you have tried. But besides those tips, I would strongly recommend thinking in plain html and not in WebForms terms, like Button_Clicks.

When you think in html, you can submit - or 'post' - a form. Exactly as you have already discovered, one form can post to one action. But there is nothing stopping you for creating several forms on your page.

This is definitely not the most eloquent solution, but it is exactly what you are asking for and it will work:

```
<!-- button1 -->
@Html.BeginForm("Action1", "ControllerName", new { ... parameters ... }) {
    <button type="submit">Button1</button>
}

<!-- button2 -->
@Html.BeginForm("Action2", "ControllerName", new { ... parameters ... }) {
    <button type="submit">Button2</button>
}
```

Repeat it at will and you can have the greatest button galore you can imagine. Look into Html.AjaxForm instead of Html.BeginForm if you want to create an AJAX call, rather than a form post.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, Max. And I gave you an answer. Please elaborate what you didn't like about the answer?

Comment: Try using `<input type="submit" />` instead of type=button.

Comment: No, its not working as expected, my test method just returns void.  the web page throws an error saying no associated view? just want it to return where it was.  now i have to add a new View?  just want it to work on data in the background and update some menu item.   why does it need to have a view to regenerate the entire page contents?  why cant it do some subroutine on another bit of code and go back where it was?

Comment: There are four questions in your last comment. This makes it hard for everyone to know what you are doing exactly. Perhaps you should update your original question with a full, reproducible example of all of your code - and perhaps create a more specific questions. Tip: take your time and think thoroughly before writing.